# How to assign the checkbox to a certain data in database using C#

Tags: c#

I am creating a logbook system where students don't need to type their information as it is stored in database already. For them to log, they just need to tick the checkbox for In if they get inside the library and Out if they get outside the library. In my DataGrid View, it displays the Student Number, Name, Course and the In & Out checkbox in rows.

My question is: how will I know that the ticked checkbox was for John? Or for Marie? Or for Dave? And how to put that log in the database table for logs?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Comment: Cant tell what? I mean what do you mean?

Comment: Maybe you should provide student-ID for the Identifiation of students

Comment: How are you displaying the check boxes with the student name?

Comment: Im displaying the name, course, and the checkboxes in a row.

Answer (score 0):

```
   //designing a checkbox inside datagrid
                               <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{StaticResource _status}" Width="Auto">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox x:Name="chk" Click="Click_SelectionChanged_1"/>                
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

     void Click_SelectionChanged_1(....)
     {
       CheckBox c=(CheckBox)sender;
       bool _stat=c.IsChecked;

         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tableStudent SET Status="+_stat+" WHERE id="+_dbid, con))
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
     }  


    int _dbid=-1; 
   //get selected id from datagrid selection change
    void datagrid_SelectionChange(.....)
    {
                DataRowView row = (DataRowView)t_bill_itemsDataGrid.SelectedItems[0];
                string s = row["id"].ToString();
                _dbid = int.Parse(s);
    }
```